# Есть форма. Как сделать перевод каретки с одного инпута на другой, если выполнилось определенное условие?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Как сделать так, чтобы при введении 2 чисел в `<input id = "h">` каретка перемещалась на следующий инпут `<input id = "m">`?

[Код](https://codepen.io/deloop/pen/dggvLd):

HTML:

```
<input type = "number" id = "h" placeholder = "Часы">:
<input type = "number" id = "m" placeholder = "Минуты">
```

CSS:

```
input {
  width: 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function moveIfTwo(aText) {
  if (aText.length == 2 && !isNaN(+aText)) {
    document.getElementById("m").focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="h" oninput="moveIfTwo(this.value)">
<input id="m">
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.getElementById('h').oninput = function(){
  if(this.value.length > 1){
    document.getElementById('m').focus();
  }
};
```

```html
<input id="h" maxlength="2">
<input id="m">
```